# Is there any protective sealant or bladder within a motorcycle tank?

Tags: motorcycle, fuel-system, fuel-tank

I am learning metal work and will one day build my own motor cycle tank.

Do these have any internal sealing or bladder?

Comment: A tank might have a protective sealant or lining, but it would probably be something added later to address rust or leaks. Fuel bladders are more common in marine application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Typically no.  My bikes with steel tanks don't come with any sealant and are definitely steel on the inside.  Same with alloy tanks. Plastic tanks now sometimes come with sealant to stop the ethanol warping them.

There are after-market products such as [POR-15](http://www.por15.com/POR-15-Fuel-Tank-Repair-Kit_p_62.html) that can seal tanks against corrosion however I don't know how effective they are.

Comment: This is incorrect.  All steel tanks have a liner sprayed onto the steel which is why it doesn't rust.

Comment: is this a new thing @DucatiKiller the ones I have seen are known to rust and don't have rust protection in them.

Comment: They've been sealed in the factory since the 70's.  Call a parts dept for any dealership.  The ones that you see rusted have simply wore out.

Answer (score 3):

All modern motorcycles with steel gas tanks have an internal coating that protects them against oxidation (rust).  There are many brands of sealer available if the stock sealant has been compromised, typically due to heat or old fuel sitting in the tank for an extended period of time.

This google search for 'motorcycle gas tank sealer' yielded these [results](https://www.google.com/search?q=motorcycle%20steel%20gas%20tank&oq=motorcycle%20steel%20gas%20tank&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.10889j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=motorcycle%20gas%20tank%20sealer&tbm=shop).

Good luck.